# Implementing INotfyPropertyChanged for calculated properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged, inotifycollectionchanged

I'm a bit new to MVVM, and was wondering

Let's say I have defined a `ObservableCollection<Differences> Diffs` property.
I also have the following property:

```
public bool IsSame
{
    get
    {
         return Diffs.Count == 0;
    }
 }
```

I dont get how I'm supposed to implement the `OnPropertyChanged` for `IsSame`, because it is implicit from the Diff list.

- Should I attach to the List `OnCollectionChanged` event and then check if it changes `IsSame` ?
- Should I use a backing field anyway and handle the List `OnCollectionChanged`?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I use a backing field anyway and handle the List OnCollectionChanged?

To do it correctly: Yes.

When related properties change it's up to the source to raise all events. Your main problem here is to detect when `IsSame` actually changes (ie goes from 1 to 0 or from 0 to 1). You need either a backing field or you will raise the event (much) more often then is required.

Comment: Hard choice. An extra backing field bloats the object size and may hurt performance. Unecessary events lead to unecessary memory allocations, which can also hurt performance.

Comment: @JonathanAllen - adding 1 `int` to a list should be the clear winner here.

Answer (score 1):

when ever you collection changes you should call OnPropertyChanged("IsSame"); - thats right. but when to call depends on your viewmodel logic.

edit: assume that you have an Add and Remove command, then you have to call OnPropertyChanged("IsSame"); within these methods.

Comment: should note that `OnCollectionChanged` 
When 
`if ((action == remove && collection.count == 0) || (action == add && collection.count == 1)) Raise("IsSame")`